# How to configure running heads in Memoir so they won't appear on “matter” opening pages?

Tags: header-footer, memoir, front-matter

I'm using Memoir for a book, and I am having some difficulty with the running heads. I obviously need to change something, but I can't figure out where to make the change.

The headers display correctly after `\chapter{chaptername}`, but the first page of the Preface is a starred \chapter*{Prefácio}, and it puts "Lista de Figuras" (list of figures) in the header.

So, how do I get it configured correctly so no header will be used on “matter” opening pages, like the first page of the Preface or the first page of the Table of Contents?

I'm still a raw noob at LaTeX, so any help is welcome. Thanks!

```
% The minimal example %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
}
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother


% Book's title and subtitle
\title{\Huge \textbf{Book Title}}
% Subtitle \\ \huge Suntitle
% Author 
\author{\textsc{Author's Name}\thanks{\url{www.example.com}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle


\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to...
\end{dedication}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%\listoftables


\mainmatter


\chapter*{Preface}
\markboth{Preface}{Preface} %%%==>this doesn't keep the header style.
\lipsum


\chapter{Introduction Chapter}

\begin{chapquote}{Edward J. Phelps, \textit{Source of this quote}}
``The man who makes no mistakes does not usually make anything.''
\end{chapquote}

\section{Section heading}
\lipsum[4]


\section{Another section heading}
\lipsum[4]


\bibliographystyle{bababbrv}
\bibliography{refs}
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The starred version does not touch the headers, you'll need to do that manually, eg using `\markboth{Preface}{Preface}` or similar. Just add it after the starred chapter command

Comment: @daleif -- That works, but it doesn't retain the header style. Is there a command to just omit the header? Thank you!

Comment: If you need it to be empty just give empty arguments

Comment: @daleif -- can you give examples of empty arguments? - I've tried adding \pagestyle{plain} immediately after \markboth{Preface}{Preface}, but this removed all the headers. Would be nice to find a way to suppress only this chapter's header or keep the header with the header style.

Comment: Please post some code. I do not understand what you want. Generally we do not like having to go to other sites to get the code.

Comment: Otherwise put a pagestyle plain at the start of front matter and a headings or what ever at the start of the main matter

Comment: I've updated my question posting some code.

Comment: `\markboth{}{}` would be empty arguments. You can also define a page style: `\makepagestyle{claud} `\makeevenhead{claud}{}{}{} \makeoddhead{claud}{}{}{} `\makeevenfoot{claud}{}{}{} `\makeoddfoot{claud}{}{}{}` (where the three `{}` respectively indicate the 'left', 'centre', and 'right' side of the header or footer); then you issue `\pagestyle{claud}` where you want empty headers and footers. But remember that `\chapter` commands usually issue a `\thispagestyle{plain}` behind the scenes.

Comment: By the way, it will be helpful in the future if you post only a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: No problem. I am not sure how your headers look now, but you could experiment one time (in a different `memoir`-based document) try filling the braces like so: `{LEFT}{middle}{RIGHT}` or what you like to see what they do. Note that the command `\chapterstyle{<whatever>}` will have absolutely no bearing on how your headers and footers appear. `\chapterstyle` and `\pagestyle` are completely independent -- they *must* be: not every document has a `\chapter`s.

Comment: Pagestyles are not an easy thing to tackle when you are just starting out. If you just want them to be empty, then `\markboth{}{}` is a simple hack; if you want manual text, it is easy to include that; if you want to emulate the default style, it becomes tricker. What you need to know for now is that `\chapter*` (the starred form!) does not update the 'mark' information, which is why you are getting the older headers carrying over into the new section; and `\markboth{}{}` then gives 'empty' marks to the headers; when you do `\chapter{New Chapter}` (no star!), the marks are updated again.

Comment: @jon -- one last question. I've used `\chapter*{Preface} `\markboth{}{' to suppress the header at the top right-hand corner of the page after the Preface page, but I still get a page number displayed at the top left-hand corner of this page. Is it possible to remove this page number and put it centred at the footer?

Comment: `\chapter*{Prefácio} \markboth{}{} \pagestyle{plain} \thispagestyle{plain}` then your regular content until the next chapter, at which point you put: `\chapter{Capítulo de Introção} \pagestyle{headings}`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if you just want the plain style, you can omit `\markboth{}{}` since you aren't using any of the marks, just the page number....

Comment: @jon -- Awesome!! You can do miracles with LateX. I'm taking note of everything you tell me. Thank you!

Comment: @jon Can you scribble together a quick answer? :-)

Comment: @jon Please do so. Please add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is jon's answer from the comments placed in the example document, providing empty headers in the Preface and running headers af the first chapter:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{dedication}
{
   \cleardoublepage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
   \hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\textwidth}
   \raggedright
}
{
   \end{minipage}
   \vspace*{\stretch{3}}
   \clearpage
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{}
\newenvironment{chapquote}[2][2em]
  {\setlength{\@tempdima}{#1}
   \def\chapquote@author{#2}
   \parshape 1 \@tempdima \dimexpr\textwidth-2\@tempdima\relax
   \itshape}
  {\par\normalfont\hfill--\ \chapquote@author\hspace*{\@tempdima}\par\bigskip}
\makeatother

\title{\Huge \textbf{Book Title}}
\author{\textsc{Author's Name}\thanks{\url{www.example.com}}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle


\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to...
\end{dedication}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Preface}
\markboth{}{}
\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{plain}

\lipsum

\chapter{Introduction Chapter}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{chapquote}{Edward J. Phelps, \textit{Source of this quote}}
``The man who makes no mistakes does not usually make anything.''
\end{chapquote}

\section{Section heading}
\lipsum[4]

\section{Another section heading}
\lipsum[4-10]

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{bababbrv}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{document}
```